# Making a clothes GUI

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a GUI (in roblox studio) when a character clicks on a button he or she will be given an outfit.

ServerScriptService Code

```
local Event = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
Event.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage
Event.Name = "UniformGiveEvent"
local Shirt = "rbxassetid://182645836"
local Pants = "rbxassetid://824967650"

function GiveUni(plr)
    local character = plr.Character
    local shirt = character.Shirt
    local pants = character.Pants
    shirt.ShirtTemplate = Shirt
    pants.PantsTemplate = Pants
end

Event.OnServerEvent:Connect(GiveUni)
```

GUI local script

```
local button = script.Parent.GiveUniform
local debounce = true
local UniEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("UnifromGiveEvent")

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if debounce then
         debounce = false
         UniEvent:FireServer()
    end
 end)
```

Comment: What Problem do you have specifically ? "How coul i make a clothes GUI in Roblox?" is not a very specific question. Where are you stuck specifically ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is too broad and could have too many answers. This is not the place to ask someone to show you how to do something - it's for getting answers to specific questions - so try to reword your question so that it is more specific to highlight the problems you are having when you try to implement the GUI yourself.

Comment: I just want someone to tell me where i went wrong and help me as i did state i am new to lua so a lot of these dont make sense to me, when i click the button nothing happens

Answer (score 3):

```
Event.Name = "UniformGiveEvent"
local UniEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("UnifromGiveEvent")
```

At the very least, you have a simple typo in your Event Name and the name of the child that you're waiting for.  (Unif**or**mGiveEvent/Unif**ro**mGiveEvent)

Answer (score 1):

When you fire the server, you have not sent the player to the Server. You have no arguments, which the function (`GiveUni`) requires (a player).

To fix this, simply change these two lines;

```
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function() 

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player)
```

and

```
UniEvent:FireServer()

UniEvent:FireServer(player)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, you do not need to define "player" in functions, as it is preset by ROBLOX.

Comment: I tried it but it wont work also when the character joins the game his/her clothes disappear, i don't know what is wrong.

Comment: @RobloxDev Check the clothes IDs exist, generally people do not have any clothes if the assets do not exist. If they do not exist, find the ones that do (e.g. get other ones or test with other ones.)

Comment: Yes they do exist

Comment: Do what Ben said and my code should work, thank you for helping Ben!